# type-graphql built-in Date scalar

Tags: nestjs, typegraphql

Tech: Nestjs, graphql (schema first)

When I make custom scalar named with 'Datetime' and change it to typescript using auto generation, 'export type DateTime = any' is created.

When I make custom scalar named with 'Json' and change it to typescript using auto generation, 'export type Json = any' is created.

But, when I make custom scalar named with 'Date' and change it to typescript using auto generation, there is no 'export type Date = any'.

It acts javascript built-in 'Date' object.

'https://typegraphql.com/docs/scalars.html' <== Docs says they provide built-in Date scalar type, and is this exactly equals with javascript Date object?